# Как объединить несколько ячеек таблицы в одну с rowspan

Tags: html, html5

Пытаюсь объединить несколько ячеек из каждой строки в одну, использую `rowspan`. В первой строке и для нужной колонки это работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почему то у следующих `<tr>` слева появляется лишний `<td>` - выделил красным прямоугольником.

Как видно для первой строки это стработало.

[Код HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/kcLupmn8/):

```
<table _ngcontent-c5="" class="HTMLGrid padding-top-twenty table">



      <thead _ngcontent-c5="">
      <tr _ngcontent-c5="">
        <th _ngcontent-c5="" class="border-left-corner">Предметы/Дата</th>
        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><th _ngcontent-c5="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="">
          <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">01.06.2018</div>
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="week">Пятница</div>
          </div>
        </th><th _ngcontent-c5="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="">
          <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">02.06.2018</div>
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="week">Суббота</div>
          </div>
        </th><th _ngcontent-c5="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="">
          <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">03.06.2018</div>
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="week">Воскресенье</div>
          </div>
        </th><th _ngcontent-c5="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="">
          <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">04.06.2018</div>
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="week">Понедельник</div>
          </div>
        </th><th _ngcontent-c5="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="">
          <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">05.06.2018</div>
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="week">Вторник</div>
          </div>
        </th><th _ngcontent-c5="" class="border-right-corner" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
          <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">06.06.2018</div>
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="week">Среда</div>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody _ngcontent-c5="">
      <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><tr _ngcontent-c5="" class="">



        <td _ngcontent-c5="" class="subject" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <span _ngcontent-c5="">Астрономия</span>
        </td>


        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-01 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-02 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-03 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn blue" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="blue">
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span _ngcontent-c5="" mdtooltipposition="above" ng-reflect-position="above" ng-reflect-message="Text"><i _ngcontent-c5="" class="material-icons">warning</i>
                  </span><!---->
            2
          </div><div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn red" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="red">
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span _ngcontent-c5="" mdtooltipposition="above" ng-reflect-position="above" ng-reflect-message="Text"><i _ngcontent-c5="" class="material-icons">warning</i>
                  </span><!---->
            2
          </div><div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn maroon" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="maroon">
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span _ngcontent-c5="" mdtooltipposition="above" ng-reflect-position="above" ng-reflect-message="Text"><i _ngcontent-c5="" class="material-icons">warning</i>
                  </span><!---->
            5
          </div>
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-04 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" rowspan="4" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-05 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn red" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="red">
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
            2
          </div><div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn red" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="red">
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
            2
          </div><div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn red" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="red">
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
            5
          </div>
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-06 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td>
      </tr><tr _ngcontent-c5="" class="">



        <td _ngcontent-c5="" class="subject" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <span _ngcontent-c5="">Аварский язык</span>
        </td>


        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="1" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-01 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
}--><div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn red" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="red">
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
            5
          </div>
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="1" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-02 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="1" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-03 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="1" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-04 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
}--><div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn red" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="red">
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span _ngcontent-c5="" mdtooltipposition="above" ng-reflect-position="above" ng-reflect-message="Text"><i _ngcontent-c5="" class="material-icons">warning</i>
                  </span><!---->
            2
          </div>
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="1" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-05 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="1" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-06 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td>
      </tr><tr _ngcontent-c5="" class="">



        <td _ngcontent-c5="" class="subject" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <span _ngcontent-c5="">Азербайджанский язык</span>
        </td>


        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="2" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-01 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="2" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-02 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
}--><div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn blue" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="blue">
                  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
            4
          </div>
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="2" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-03 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="2" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-04 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="2" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-05 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="2" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-06 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td>
      </tr><tr _ngcontent-c5="" class="">



        <td _ngcontent-c5="" class="subject" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <span _ngcontent-c5="">Умелые руки</span>
        </td>


        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="3" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-01 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="3" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-02 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="3" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-03 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="3" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-04 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="3" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-05 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td><td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="3" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-06 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Добавте код из ссылки прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо - добавляю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код ужасно неудобно читать. Но по тому что я вижу вы объединили столбик ячеек и видимо все-равно добавили те `<td>` которые объединили. Их не нужно добавлять если вы объединили ячейки.

http://jsfiddle.net/kcLupmn8/6/ - ваш код

http://jsfiddle.net/kcLupmn8/7/ - форматированный код

```
<table _ngcontent-c5="" class="HTMLGrid padding-top-twenty table">
   <thead _ngcontent-c5="">
      <tr _ngcontent-c5="">
         <th _ngcontent-c5="" class="border-left-corner">Предметы/Дата</th>
         <!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
            }-->
         <th _ngcontent-c5="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="">
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">
               <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">01.06.2018</div>
               <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="week">Пятница</div>
            </div>
         </th>
         <th _ngcontent-c5="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="">
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">
               <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">02.06.2018</div>
               <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="week">Суббота</div>
            </div>
         </th>
         <th _ngcontent-c5="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="">
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">
               <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">03.06.2018</div>
               <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="week">Воскресенье</div>
            </div>
         </th>
         <th _ngcontent-c5="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="">
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">
               <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">04.06.2018</div>
               <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="week">Понедельник</div>
            </div>
         </th>
         <th _ngcontent-c5="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="">
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">
               <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">05.06.2018</div>
               <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="week">Вторник</div>
            </div>
         </th>
         <th _ngcontent-c5="" class="border-right-corner" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">
               <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="date">06.06.2018</div>
               <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="week">Среда</div>
            </div>
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody _ngcontent-c5="">
      <!--bindings={
         "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
         }-->
      <tr _ngcontent-c5="" class="">
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" class="subject" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <span _ngcontent-c5="">Астрономия</span>
         </td>
         <!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
            }-->
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-01 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-02 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-03 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
               }-->
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn blue" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="blue">
               <!--bindings={
                  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
                  }--><span _ngcontent-c5="" mdtooltipposition="above" ng-reflect-position="above" ng-reflect-message="Text"><i _ngcontent-c5="" class="material-icons">warning</i>
               </span><!---->
               2
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn red" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="red">
               <!--bindings={
                  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
                  }--><span _ngcontent-c5="" mdtooltipposition="above" ng-reflect-position="above" ng-reflect-message="Text"><i _ngcontent-c5="" class="material-icons">warning</i>
               </span><!---->
               2
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn maroon" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="maroon">
               <!--bindings={
                  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
                  }--><span _ngcontent-c5="" mdtooltipposition="above" ng-reflect-position="above" ng-reflect-message="Text"><i _ngcontent-c5="" class="material-icons">warning</i>
               </span><!---->
               5
            </div>
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-04 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" rowspan="4" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-05 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
               }-->
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn red" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="red">
               <!--bindings={
                  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
                  }-->
               2
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn red" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="red">
               <!--bindings={
                  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
                  }-->
               2
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn red" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="red">
               <!--bindings={
                  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
                  }-->
               5
            </div>
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-06 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr _ngcontent-c5="" class="">
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" class="subject" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <span _ngcontent-c5="">Аварский язык</span>
         </td>
         <!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
            }-->
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="1" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-01 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
               }-->
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn red" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="red">
               <!--bindings={
                  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
                  }-->
               5
            </div>
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="1" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-02 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="1" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-03 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="1" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-04 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
               }-->
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn red" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="red">
               <!--bindings={
                  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
                  }--><span _ngcontent-c5="" mdtooltipposition="above" ng-reflect-position="above" ng-reflect-message="Text"><i _ngcontent-c5="" class="material-icons">warning</i>
               </span><!---->
               2
            </div>
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="1" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-06 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr _ngcontent-c5="" class="">
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" class="subject" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <span _ngcontent-c5="">Азербайджанский язык</span>
         </td>
         <!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
            }-->
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="2" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-01 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="2" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-02 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
               }-->
            <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="plus-btn blue" ng-reflect-klass="plus-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="blue">
               <!--bindings={
                  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
                  }-->
               4
            </div>
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="2" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-03 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="2" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-04 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="2" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-05 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr _ngcontent-c5="" class="">
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" class="subject" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <span _ngcontent-c5="">Умелые руки</span>
         </td>
         <!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
            }-->
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="3" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-01 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="3" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-02 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="3" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-03 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="3" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-04 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c5="" approwspan="" ng-reflect-rows="4" ng-reflect-index="3" ng-reflect-dt="2018-06-06 00:00:00.000" style="width: 14.28%;">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
               }-->
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```